# Reuse TextureView with different videoplayers

Tags: android, surface

I have the following situation:

In activity A's layout I have `<TextureView .../>` on full screen. Into the activity A class I create `new Surface(surfaceTexture)` using TextureView's `SurfaceTexture`. Also I have VideoPlayer1 and pass to him the newly created surface via `.setSurface(mySurface)`. So far so good, the video is rendered and everything is perfect, but in some moment of the user interaction, I release the current `videoPlayer1` fully, create new instance (`videoPlayer2`) and call `videoPlayer2.setSurface(mySurface)`. The problem is that for `videoPlayer2`, `mySurface` doesn't render anything. I tried almost everything.

I'm unable to show code, but what is the correct practice to reuse single Surface instance for different VideoPlayers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What did you do when you release the current videoPlayer1?

Did you try player.setSurface(null) and player.release()?

I think you can have a try.